# Azure connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ip:443

Tags: c#, web-services, azure

So I implemented an interface to communicate with a rest web service using the `HttpClient` class to make requests.

The code works perfectly locally, but when I deploy to Azure my application can't fire the request, it crashes on this line:

```
using (var response = await HttpClient.PostAsync(uri, content)) { ... }
// uri = https://api-rest.zenvia360.com.br/services/send-sms
```

The exact exception message is this:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond 200.203.125.26:443
```

The web service provider states that "if you use firewall or proxy you must add and exception for our IPs. For HTTPS, use port 443:

200.203.125.24

200.203.125.25

**200.203.125.26** (the ip of the exception message)

200.203.125.27

200.203.125.28

200.203.125.29"

I looked everywhere in Azure looking for a firewall or something and I got nothing. Also this exception message is pretty cryptc. I tested the same code with another url (fired a post to www.gooogle.com) and it worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be on the web service side. The service I'm using blocks international requests by default. I asked them to whitelist the azure outbound IPs and now it works.